# PHP SQLite - Not returning correct count of match

Tags: php, sqlite

I am using PHP lite to search for a matching row like this...

```
$count = $db->exec("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '34534fgr'");
echo $count;
```

But my count is returning 1 every time, even when the value does not exist.

Am I searching incorrectly?

Comment: Assuming you're using PHP's SQLite class, exec returns a boolean: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php. It's not generally used by select. You'll should use the query call: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php

Answer (score 0):

```
Am I searching incorrectly?
```

yup. protip: when debugging, use `var_dump` instead of `echo`, it would help you see the issue here, because it would print `bool(true);` instead of `int(1)` or `string("1")`, because PDO::exec() returns a boolean.

here's how to do what you *tried* to do:

```
$count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE userid = '34534fgr'",PDO::FETCH_NUM)->fetch()[0];
```